# Converting web service response to JSON objects with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, serialization, alamofire

I am using a web service which has response in German language. I am trying to parse the son as following:

```
alamoFireManager.request(urlString,method: .get, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:headers).validate().responseJSON {  [unowned self] (response) in
    debugPrint(response)
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
      handler(true,value,nil)
    case .failure:
      self.errorhandler(response, ComepletionHandler: handler)
    }
  }
```

But I am getting following error because of German language:

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to convert data to string around character 1819." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around character 1819.}))

Although I am getting data in response.data but Alamofire is not able to convert it to valid JSON response. Response is something l

> Aufbrechen von Kan\ufffdlen f\ufffdr die Verlegung von Rohren bei Sanit\ufffdranwendungen

How can I fix it?

Comment: replace this `responseJSON` to `responseData`

Answer (score 0):

`responseJSON` will pass a JSON object into its completion. i.e. it will be a dictionary or array with String keys and JSON compatible values.

You should use `responseData` for the type of `String` not `JSON`

```
 alamoFireManager.request(urlString,method: .get, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:headers).validate().responseData {  [unowned self] (response) in
        debugPrint(response)
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
          handler(true,value,nil)
        case .failure:
          self.errorhandler(response, ComepletionHandler: handler)
        }
      }
```